# G-storage bucket: If a, web UI, file upload is cancelled, and re-uploaded, will the files be overwritten, or duplicated?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Currently uploading 6,500 csv files from a public bank FDIC dataset. It's taken 8 hours to upload 50% of the 25gb files (the files are less than 5mb each).

[image]
Question: 
If the upload is cancelled, then a new upload is started with the same files into the same storage bucket folder, will the already uploaded files be overwritten or duplicated when the second upload adds files to the bucket folder? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it reaches the first object that already exists, it will give you a prompt allowing you to choose between:

- Replace existing object
- Skip uploading object

and a check box to:

- Repeat for all remaining conflicts